# Where did the notion of 'vaughtian pair' come from?

Tags: model-theory

I can see the notion of vaughtian pair is crutial in Morley's categoricity theorem but I don't know exact intuition behind this notion. Is this concept corresponds to some algebra notions like pregeomtry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I'm 100% confident in my answer, though it may give you an idea.

Morley and Vaught wrote in the journal for *Mathematica Scandinavica* (Vol.11, No.1 1963 pp37-57) and proved Vaught's two cardinal theorem. This was proved in 6.2 of the journal article.

For two cardinals $\lambda>\mu>\omega$, a two cardinal $(\lambda, \mu)$-model of a theory $T$ is a model $\mathcal{M}\vDash T$ of size $\lambda$ with a definable subset $\phi(\mathcal{M})$ of size $\mu$. The two cardinal theorem states that if $T$ has a $(\lambda, \mu)$-model, then it has a $(\omega_1, \omega)$-model.

In 6.2 of the article, I believe they make use of these Vaughtian pairs, though they do not refer to these with such a name. Certainly other books such as *Model Theory: An Introduction* by D. Marker, or *A Course In Model Theory* by K. Tent and M.Ziegler proves the two cardinal theorem using Vaught pairs. It might be in the journal that the concept of Vaughtian pair is created, though I recommend you read the article to verify the claim.

Of course, the notion of Vaughtian pair does correlate with pregeometry highly. We know that if a complete (also countable?) theory $T$ has no Vaught Pairs, then any definable minimal set of a model is also strongly minimal. It was observed (for example by Baldwin and Lachland) that in strongly minimal sets, one could define a closure operator which defines a pregeometry on the set. However, it is not guaranteed that $T$ would contain a definable minimal set, although it is guaranteed when $T$ is $\omega$-stable.

These two hypotheses are key in the Baldwin-Lachlan characterisation of uncountably categorical theories: $T$ is uncountably categorical for any given uncountable cardinal $\kappa$ if and only if $T$ is $\omega$-stable and has no Vaught pairs. For the 'if' direction of this theorem, by what was discussed above, we can find a strongly minimal set in some model, and in this set there will be a notion of dimension well defined. One can also prove that because $T$ is $\omega$-stable,  there is a prime model of $T$ prime over this strongly minimal set. After some more work (arguably a lot more work than outlined here) using the idea of dimension of the strongly minimal sets, one can show that any two uncountable models of the same size of $T$ must be isomorphic.